# General rules of passing/returning reference of array (not pointer) to/from a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, compile-time

We can pass reference of an array to a function like:

```
void f(int (&a)[5]);

int x[5];
f(x);     //okay
int y[6];
f(y);     //error - type of y is not `int (&)[5]`.
```

Or even better, we can write a function template:

```
template<size_t N>
void f(int (&a)[N]); //N is size of the array!

int x[5];
f(x);     //okay - N becomes 5
int y[6];
f(y);     //okay - N becomes 6
```

---

Now my question is, how to return reference of an array from a function?

I want to return array of folllowing types from a function:

```
int a[N];
int a[M][N];
int (*a)[N];
int (*a)[M][N];
```

where `M` and `N` is known at compile time!

What are general rules for passing and returning compile-time reference of an array to and from a function? How can we pass reference of an array of type `int (*a)[M][N]` to a function?

EDIT:

**Adam** commented : `int (*a)[N]` is not an array, it's a pointer to an array.

Yes. But one dimension is known at compile time! How can we pass this information which is known at compile time, to a function?

Comment: `int (*a)[N]` is not an array, it's a pointer to an array.

Comment: @Adam: Yes. But one dimension is known at compile time!

Comment: Simplify your life:  Use `typedef` and `std::vector`.  Pass by reference.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I know this is comment necromancy but that's a terrible suggestion. If he were to use an stl container to replace a compile time known bounds array he would use `std::array` not `std::vector`.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode:  You may not have noticed that the date of the post is 2011, and C++11 may not have been available.  The std::array is a C++11 feature.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews even so, you shouldn't replace a statically sized array with a dynamically resized array if you need compile-time size

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you want to return a reference to an array from a function, the declaration would look like this:

```
// an array
int global[10];

// function returning a reference to an array
int (&f())[10] {
   return global;
}
```

The declaration of a function returning a reference to an array looks the same as the declaration of a variable that is a reference to an array - only that the function name is followed by `()`, which may contain parameter declarations:

```
int (&variable)[1][2];
int (&functionA())[1][2];
int (&functionB(int param))[1][2];
```

Such declarations can be made much clearer by using a typedef:

```
typedef int array_t[10];

array_t& f() {
   return global;
}
```

If you want it to get really confusing, you can declare a function that takes a reference to an array and also returns such a reference:

```
template<int N, int M>
int (&f(int (&param)[M][N]))[M][N] {
   return param;
}
```

*Pointers* to arrays work the same, only that they use `*` instead of `&`.

Comment: +1. Great. I wanted something like this. Now please pass and return other types as well. My question has several types. Also explain the rules!

Comment: The last example is used in a common snippet to obtain the size of an array as a static constant: `template <typename T, int N> char (&size_detail( T (&)[N] ))[N]; #define sizeof_array( a ) sizeof( size_detail(a) )`

Comment: Also: noexcept and const (for methods) still goes after the argments. E.g. const noexept method `foo` that returns a reference to an int array of size 10 and takes a single char argument is declared as `int (&foo(char) const noexcept)[10];`. At that point, its probably better to use typedefs or trailing returns.

Comment: How do we specify such a function is a `const` member function?

Comment: @Ayxan: See Artyer's comment

Answer (score 12):

With C++11's trailing return type syntax, you can also write:

```
auto foo () -> int (&)[3]
{
    static int some_array[3]; // doesn't have to be declared here
    return some_array; // return a reference to the array.
}
```

Comment: Which returns a reference to an int array of three elements.

Comment: Ooh wow this is a really neat feature. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/introduction_to_the_c_11_feature_trailing_return_types?lang=en

Answer (score 9):

You cannot return an array from a function.

8.3.5/6:

> Functions shall not have a return type
>   of type array or function, although
>   they may have a return type of type
>   pointer or reference to such things.

EDIT: You'll love the syntax:

```
int (&bar()) [5] {
  static int x[5];
  return x;
}


int (* & bar()) [6][10] {
    static int x[6][10];
    static int (*y)[6][10] = &x;
    return y;
}
// Note - this returns a reference to a pointer to a 2d array, not exactly what you wanted.
```

Comment: Erik, I made it *reference* in my question. Now please answer!

Comment: @Nawaz: Have fun. Now please typedef this makes my head hurt :P

Answer (score 3):

As [Erik mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398930/general-rules-of-passing-returning-an-array-not-pointer-to-from-a-function/5398968#5398968), you can't return an array from a function.  You can return a pointer or a reference, although the syntax is quite hairy:

```
// foo returns a pointer to an array 10 of int
int (*foo(float arg1, char arg2))[10] { ... }

// bar returns a reference to an array 10 of int
int (&foo(float arg1, char arg2))[10] { ... }
```

I'd strongly recommend making a typedef for the array type:

```
// IntArray10 is an alias for "array 10 of int"
typedef int IntArray10[10];

// Equivalent to the preceding definitions
IntArray10 *foo(float arg1, char arg2) { ... }
IntArray10 &bar(float arg1, char arg2) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Supplemental to the fine answer by sth, here is how to declare a class with a constant method returning an array reference:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    const int (&getIntArray() const)[10];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tagged C++, so I'm going to suggest that the way to return an array in C++ is to return a `std::vector` and not try any trickery with C-arrays (which should be used only in carefully selected scenarios in C++ code).

As other answers noted, you can't return C-arrays from functions.

Comment: That is if you're fine with 16 bytes of overhead every time you pass it around.