# Class accept and return array

Tags: c++, arrays

I try to create a class that accept and return an array but I got some problem. I'm not sure if it is legal to return an array from a class. Or it could be done by returning an pointer to the array. Thank for any solution to the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myclass {
private:
    int Array[10];

public:
    myclass (int temp[10]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Array [i] = temp [i];
        }
    }


    int returnArray () {
        return Array; // error here, I'm not sure if it is legal to return an array.
    }

    int* returnArray2 () {
        return this->Array; // hope it will return a pointer to the array
    }
};


int main () {
    int Array[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    myclass A(Array);
    cout << A.returnArray() << endl; // try to return an array and print it.

    myclass* ptr = &A;
    cout << *ptr->returnArray2 << endl; // error here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you going to do with the array? What is your goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it is better to write the constructor either like

```
myclass ( const int ( &temp )[10] ) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Array [i] = temp [i];
    }
}
```

or like

```
myclass ( int temp[], size_t n ) : Array {} {

    if ( n > 10 ) n = 10;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Array [i] = temp [i];
    }
}
```

Or even you may define the both constructors.

As for the returning value then you may not return an array. You may return either a reference to an array or a pointer to the entire array or a pointer to its first element

For example

```
int ( &returnArray () )[10] {
    return Array; 
}
```

In this case you can write in main

```
for ( int x : A.returnArray() ) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

As for this statement

```
cout << *ptr->returnArray2 << endl; // error here
```

then you forgot to place parentheses after returnArray2. Write

```
cout << *ptr->returnArray2() << endl;
```

And the following member function is wrong because the expression in the return statement has type `int *` while the return type of the function is `int`

```
int returnArray () {
    return Array; // error here, I'm not sure if it is legal to return an array.
}
```

So either the function will coincide with the the second member function if you specify its return type like `int *`. Or you could change the return expression to `*Array`

Comment: Thank you for your solution and it is what I need. The syntax "int ( &returnArray () )[10]  {} "is new to me because I started to learn C++ for only few weeks.

Comment: @goofy Beginners should help each other.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
int returnArray () {
    return Array; // error here, I'm not sure if it is legal to return an array.
}
```

This is illegal because `Array` is not of `int` type. Your `returnArray2` is valid, however. As for this line:

```
cout << *ptr->returnArray2 << endl; // error here
```

This is illegal because `returnArray2` is a *function*; you must call it to return the `int*`:

```
cout << *ptr->returnArray2() << endl; // prints the first value in the array
```

Other notes:

- Your capitalization is backwards; you should call your class `MyClass` and your member array `arr` or `arr_`, or you will confuse a lot of people.
- `return this->Array;` this is redundant, you can simply `return Array;`
- If you haven't heard of `std::vector` and `std::array` you should research those, as they are generally superior to C-style arrays.

Comment: Your first "note" is highly subjective. Though I use the same convention that you do, please don't posit it as an absolute!

Comment: I suppose so...although it's confusing when SE colors `Array` as a typename!

Comment: Only if that's not your style!

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would suggest to read a c++ book to get your basics correct as there are lot of issues in the code you posted.

Regarding your main question about exposing C style arrays in class public API, this is not a very robust mechanism. Do it if it is absolutely essential because of existing code but if possible prefer to use std::vector. You will mostly always end up with better code.

Other answers have corrected your coding errors, so i won't repeat that.

One other thing, your code suggests that the array size is fixed. You can pass and return the array by reference as well. Refer to: [General rules of passing/returning reference of array (not pointer) to/from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398930/general-rules-of-passing-returning-reference-of-array-not-pointer-to-from-a-fu)