# Pass a reference to an array

Tags: c++, arrays

Considering I have the following array:

```
int * a = new int[1000];
```

I would like to pass this array to a function by reference. If I would be calling this function from `main`:

```
int main()
{
    int * a = new int[1000];
    func(a);
    //print the elements of the array
    for(int i=1;i<=sizeof(a);i++) cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

My function would be:

```
void func( ??? )
{
//write some elements in the array
for(int i=1;i<=sizeof(a);i++) a[i]=i;
}
```

How do I have to declare `func`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [General rules of passing/returning reference of array (not pointer) to/from a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398930/general-rules-of-passing-returning-reference-of-array-not-pointer-to-from-a-fu)

Comment: You do not have an array.  You have a pointer.  You will have to pass a size with it to the function.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector`?

Answer (score 3):

Well the primary flaw is that `sizeof(a)` doesn't do what you think it does, if `int * a;` is passed to your function. It just calculates the size of the pointer variable itself at compile time. There's no information kept with the pointer that it was allocated using `new int[1000];` and the size was `1000`.

You need to pass the array size explicitly with an additional parameter, or better use `std::vector<int> a(1000);` at all.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just pass `a`,
It should be,

```
func(a,1000);
```

Your function will be,

void func( ??? ) -->  `void func( int *a, size_t size)

Comment: This is wrong. `a` is a pointer, so `sizeof(a)` will (probably) be 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to accept an array of integers of a certain size.

```
void func(int (&arr)[1000]) {
  // insert logic here
}
```

The above will only accept **`int` arrays** of size *1000* - no more, no less.

You are not passing an array, though. You're passing a pointer, so you need to pass the size:

```
void func(int *arr, size_t n) {
  // insert logic here
}
```