# How to use a cv-qualifier for a method that returns a reference to an array?

Tags: c++

If I have a member function which returns a reference to an array (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5399014/4304120), how can I add a const qualifier to the function? This code doesn't compile under Visual C++ 2010.

```
struct A
{
    int data[10];

    // this compiles
    const int (&f1())[10]
    {
        return data;
    }

    // error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<cv-qualifer>'
    const int (&f2())[10] const
    {
        return data;
    }
};
```

Comment: Since C++14 you can avoid the problem with `const auto& f2() const { return data; }`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
const int (&f2() const )[10]
{
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Would reference qualifiers also go in the `()` around the function name an parameter list?

Comment: @NathanOliver I got your question correctly, no you can't do `int (const&f2() const )[10]`

Comment: @101010 No the `&` or `&&` at then end of member function to determine if they they are lvalue or rvalue only functions.

Comment: @MarianSpanik You got what you've asked for :)

Comment: @NathanOliver yes they'd go after the `const` and before anything else

Comment: @M.M Thanks for that

Answer (score 22):

I'll propose few solutions which are in my opinion more readable than the extremely direct answer to this question. I'm sure there are C grammar enthusiasts out there and I apologize to them for I have terrible memory and I'm not able to remember those C rules.

#### Type alias

You can avoid the weird C-based grammar by using a type alias:

```
struct A {
    using data_type = int[10];
    data_type data;
    data_type& f1() { return data; }
    data_type const& f2() const { return data; }
};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fcb7368be9d1ad9c)

or with `typedef` (for before C++11):

```
struct A {
    typedef int data_type[10];
    data_type data;
    data_type& f1() { return data; }
    data_type const& f2() const { return data; }
};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4759c37e3bd9e5e)

#### Auto

Since C++14 you can also use `auto` return types:

```
struct A {
    int data[10];
    auto& f1() { return data; }
    auto const& f2() const { return data; }
};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86f47b1d8d19917b)

#### Standard array

As of C++11 you can also just use `std::array`:

```
struct A {
    using data_type = std::array<int, 10>;
    data_type data;
    data_type& f1() { return data; }
    data_type const& f2() const { return data; }
};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94c6d9e0d37156dc)

and simplify it to:

```
struct A {
    std::array<int, 10> data;
};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9dd80969e6c9471)

which is somewhat functionally equivalent but easier on the eyes.

Comment: Aren't you missing a const in your fist example?

Comment: @MohamadElghawi Thank you.

Comment: Can't we also have a clean but exact return type using a trailing return type?

Comment: @Morwenn What do you mean? Something like `... -> const auto&`?

Comment: More like `auto ... -> int const(&)[10]` in which case you have the actual return type fully spelled out, but without the awkawrd C-style function syntax nested in it.

Comment: This is the sane solution to the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Use a typedef. It'll make everybody's life easier:

```
struct A
{
    using Data = int[10];
    Data data;

    Data const& f1()
    {
        return data;
    }

    Data const& f2() const
    {
        return data;
    }
};
```

The same could be accomplished with `std::array<int, 10>`:

```
std::array<int, 10> data;
std::array<int, 10> const& f2() const { return data; }
```

which is another advantage of `std::array` over raw array.

Answer (score 4):

Well a typedef could solve your problem, and make it a little more readable:

```
struct A
{
    typedef int array_t[10];

    ...

    const array_t& f2() const
    {
        return data;
    }
};
```

Comment: I am sorry, I spelled the question incorrectly. I want to add the qualifier to the function, not the return value.

Comment: It's teh same thing though. You can use the `typedef` and then add `const` after the function like usual

Comment: Yes, exactly. Edit made

Comment: Using C `typedef` kinda just exchanges one readability problem for another, due to the element and alias types being the wrong way around conceptually and versus all other uses. Using C++ `using` is superior. In fact, this might be a 'textbook' example of why the latter was added to C++.

Comment: @underscore_d what do you mean? Typedef is same way around as variables being defined. So what *other uses* did you mean?

Comment: @JDługosz I think what _underscore_d_ means here is that `typedef` can be seen as inconsistent when used for array/function declarations - `typedef int myType` vs. `typedef int arrayType[10]` - one would probably expect `typedef int[10] arrayType` (I realize there are rules for this and that according to them this does make sense, but I think this is what underscore_d meant). With a `using` directive, it is indeed more intuitive: `using arrayType = int[10];`.

Comment: @szczurcio Exactly. Thanks!

Comment: But that's exactly the *same* (way around) as `int array_variable [10]`, so what does *all other uses* refer to? I don't know what *element and alias types* mean in this sentence.